# Using a local python project with Poetry within a Dockerized project

Tags: python, docker, python-poetry

I have a dockerized project that uses Poetry for dependency management. I'm developing a Python library that I'm using within that dockerized project and would like to be able to make a change to that library and then use it within the project, preferably without doing more than saving those changes.

Right now, this works:

1. Make a change
2. `poetry build`
3. Copy the `*tar.gz` file into the dockerized project's root directory
4. Run `docker-compose up --build`

I've tried changing the `path` field for the project to something like, since the dockerized project and the lib both live on the same level on my filesystem:
`my-lib = {path="../my-lib", develop=true}`

Poetry can't find it, so I added a `COPY` command in my dockerfile. Docker didn't like that. I started finding a workaround for that, but thought, "Maybe somebody knows a better way."

Is there something I'm missing?

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I too am struggling with this. A few workaround that I've thought of. 1, copy the dependency that you want to use in your project to the repo you're working on and add that as a path dependency. 2, move to a different means of building a docker image (e.g. jib). Some OCI image builders don't need a docker daemon and simply assemble filesystems together.